# Concurrency level per task

Tags: celery

I need to download a large number of URLs from several domains with Celery. I have a task that downloads a single URL, does some stuff to it and then stores some data in MongoDB.

The machine that is running the task can easily handle running 64 concurrent tasks of this type, but to minimize impact on the target webserver I only want it to use four concurrent requests per domain. Is there any way to do this?

I looked at several locking examples, but they all seem to revoke a task if it can't acquire a lock in a certain amount of time.

Comment: do you have tried codes ?

Answer (score 1):

Just realised that this can easily be achieved using chains and chords, by just adding the URL visit tasks to N chains (where N is the number of concurrent downloader *per domain*.)

I can then add these chains to a single chord to run an analysis task when all URLs have been downloaded.

Comment: So I tried implementing this, but now I run into the fact that there is a limited number of tasks your can put in a single chain.